# Use React-Bootstrap Tabs with parcel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, parcel

I use react-bootstrap 2.7.4 and parcel 2.8.3.

Everytime when I import `import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs'`, I will get this exception:

```
Error: Expected content key 25835703249f5e91 to exist
    at nullthrows (.../app-react/node_modules/nullthrows/nullthrows.js:7:15)
    at ContentGraph.getNodeIdByContentKey (.../app-react/node_modules/@parcel/graph/lib/ContentGraph.js:81:38)
    at BundleGraph.getDependencies (.../app-react/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/BundleGraph.js:775:30)
    at BundleGraph.getDependencies (.../app-react/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/public/BundleGraph.js:145:24)
    at .../app-react/node_modules/@parcel/reporter-dev-server/lib/ServerReporter.js:17188:54
    at .../app-react/node_modules/@parcel/utils/lib/index.js:33551:34
    at $b0fd219fea43bcac$export$2e2bcd8739ae039._runFn (.../app-react/node_modules/@parcel/utils/lib/index.js:33579:19)
    at $b0fd219fea43bcac$export$2e2bcd8739ae039._next (.../app-react/node_modules/@parcel/utils/lib/index.js:33572:20)
    at $b0fd219fea43bcac$export$2e2bcd8739ae039._next (.../app-react/node_modules/@parcel/utils/lib/index.js:33573:38) {
  framesToPop: 1
```

I hope someone has an idea to resolve my problem.